# Run errors while trying to excute Tensorflow tutorial Classify images of clothing

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to set-up Tensorflow on my computer. And I tried to follow the tutorial on their website to see if I did everything right. I followed the first tutorial about [Classify images of Clothing](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification). But when I follow the instruction I get the following error messages:

```
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: DESKTOP-AQ46N88
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: DESKTOP-AQ46N88
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
```

I already tried to solve the first error message. And I found I didn't install all the GPU support explained on [their website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu). But now it still doesn't work and I can't figure out what the problem would be, because I've installed all the GPU support.
Could anyone explain to me what I did wrong or what I should have installed?

Answer (score 0):

I can't recall where I read this but I do recall that it was recommend that when you install tensorflow 2 you should use conda to install it and NOT pip. Apparently installing with conda will automatically install all the dependencies where as installing with pip does not. So I recommend uninstalling tensorflow then reinstall it using conda.

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with my own GPU. I did install all the requirements as mentioned on the website of Tensorflow but apparently I couldn't install everything correctly, because I do not have a NVIDIA GPU but one from Intell.